# I have a bad battery for a laptop does the voltage for the battery have to be the same as the laptops?

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a Sony personal computer Model PCG-7141L. and it says DC 19.5V on the back, but on the bad battery it says 11.1V (I'm not sure if its AC or DC)4,400mAh would the voltage difference matter when I buy a new battery?

Answer (score 1):

Charging a battery takes a higher voltage than the battery output.  A laptop input voltage of 19.5V isn't unusual for a battery voltage in the neighborhood of 11V.

Go by the battery model number to buy a replacement (it will be on the battery, and usually in the laptop specs).